How to instantiate Singleton objects for other classes in a different class in Java?
public class Singleton {
    private volatile static A AInstance = null;
    private volatile static B BInstance = null;
    
    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static synchronized A getAInstance() {
        if (AInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (AInstance  == null) {
                    AInstance  = createInstance();
                }
            }
        }
        return AInstance;
    }

    public static synchronized B getBInstance() {
        if (BInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (BInstance == null) {
                    BInstance = new B();
                }
            }
        }
        return BInstance;
    }
    
    private static A createInstance(){
        return new A();
    }
    
    public static void refreshInstance() {
        AInstance = createInstance();
    }
    
}

I have classes A and B. I need to refresh the instance of A on demand and for a normal singleton object for class B.
I can't create singleton property for these classes in their respective classes as these clases are defined in a jar file and are dependencies for my project.
Also, Singleton is required as these objects send network calls, creating object for each thread leads to 429 errors.
Is the implementation of the above singleton objects valid in a multithreaded environment?

It's not; refreshInstance() acquires no locks, so, a JVM is free to have other code that runs 'later' fail to observe the change.

Shouldn’t it be OK since AInstance  is volatile?

There could be a race if refreshInstance and getAInstance are called concurrently when AInstance is null, but that may or may not matter to your application.

There are other problems here, too. When applying the double-checked locking pattern, you don’t want to make the entire method synchronized as this defeats the optimization. If you can tolerate the synchronization overhead on every call, just use the simple implementation without the extra check.

@TimMoore, you mean that I should use the simple lazy initialisation, correct? Also, is their a way to make the refresh method thread safe too.

By definition, replacing instances is not a “Singleton”. See Wikipedia.

Yes, simple lazy initialization. If the entire method is synchronized, the inner synchronized block doesn’t have any additional benefit. The simplest way to make the refresh method thread safe is to also mark it as synchronized. Then, the question is whether the simple implementation meets the performance requirements of the application. If testing finds that it does not (and it’s better to test than to guess) then consider more optimized and complex solutions, knowing that with increased complexity comes increased risk of bugs.

Of course, in the B case where it is not refreshed with a new instance, an even simpler solution would be to initialize it eagerly and make the instance final. If that’s possible, then no synchronization is needed at all. As always, the best solution depends on the specific requirements of the application, so it’s hard to give good advice for a simplified, out-of-context example.

For example, is it a problem that after calling refreshInstance, other threads might continue to use an outdated A instance that was previously retrieved from getAInstance and that multiple instances may be in use concurrently? If so, this will need a more substantial design change that encapsulates access of the current A instance and ensures that operations with it complete before the refresh.

of cause ,this way can ensure thread-safe by your
Singleton.getXInstance()

use double check with lock is ok
you can look this article:Java Singleton Design Pattern Best Practices with Examples

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
